# Is it possible to update google dataflow job with a new pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to add a new independent pipeline to running job, and it keeps failing. Also it fails quite ungracefully, sitting in a "-" state for a long time before moving to "not started" and then failed with no errors reported.

I suspect that this may be impossible, but I cannot find confirmation anywhere.

Job id for the latest attempt is 2016-02-02_02_08_52-5813673121185917804 (it's still sitting at not started)

Answer (score 1):

Update: It should now be possible to add a PubSub source when updating a pipeline.

---

Original Response:

Thanks for reporting this problem. We have identified an issue when updating a pipeline with additional PubSub sources.

For the time being we suggest either running a new (separate) pipeline with the additional PubSub source, or stopping and starting the job over with the additional sources installed from the beginning.

Comment: Update: It should now be possible to update a pipeline with additional PubSub sources. Let us know if you continue to have problems.